# Frameset border problem in Internet explorer

Tags: html, css, frameset

I am making a frameset page with the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html>
    <frameset rows="*,65" border="0" framespacing="0" >
        <frame src="page.html" />
        <frame src="footer.html" scrolling="no" />
    </frameset>
</html>
```

It looks so nice in Firefox and Safari but not in IE8, There is still a thick ugly border above the footer. How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it was

```
frameborder="0"
```